# What is the best practice for browsing without the Tor Browser?

Tags: browsers, raspberry-pi

The Tor Browser is only available for: Intel-based 32 and 64-bit machines and only for Mac, Windows, and Linux.

However if you are using *BSD, or are using a non-Intel system such as ARM, you can use the Tor daemon but not the browser so what would be the best option for browsing on these platform?

Comment: I believe you can set up Firefox and similar to use a SOCKS proxy, and then point it to the port (on localhost or elsewhere) of the tor daemon. I believe that should work, but you may want to test it out first.

Comment: It will definitely work. I've done it before. But the question is, is this the best option?

Comment: Tor browser itself has a range of default settings and addons that a regular browser does not have. You should be able to mimic the tor browser pretty well in all aspects, but best practice? Not sure if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you could use qemu - virtual machine on *BSD.
Inside it, you could simply run LiveCD Linux, for example Kali-Linux. Thereafter, you might mount host / or / visit torproject.org to fetch fresh TorBrowser. Unzip it,... launch,... voila!

Otherwise, your profile will be highly divided from major mass of TorBrowser's users.

Even, full-screen - is noticed in TorBrowser as a bad option, because, attacker could sniff your Monitor's / Screen's Height / Width, by primitive javascript.

From the other side, they will be able only see, that you are on *BSD and using default firefox via socks5 of source-builded tor-daemon. Plus Width and Height of your Monitor.... Not so bad, it is not your home address... It is something, that shall be changed in half of year anyway, because of simple system's / browser's updates / upgrades. Plus, you will probably, someday, bough yourself another monitor.

In other word, if u are looking to only bypass unfriendly fascist firewall in your beautiful country, you could use any browser via socks5 of default Tor daemon or even just use DigitalOcean to setup openvpn server for yourself.